# Find p-MOS frow battery switch application

Tags: mosfet, digital-logic, battery-charging, switching, pmos

I'm designing a switching circuit between USB (5V) and Battery (li-ion 3.7V) for a portable device, below is shown the schematic: 
[image: Schematic]

As you can see if correctly chosen the P-MOS switches between USB and Battery, indeed I actually have a problem choosing the right MOS.
Let me explain:
Suppose Usb is not attached then we only have the the Battery. Then at the DCDC input I must have at least 3.5V (200mV dropout). I've 2 question:

Since I cannot afford any voltage drop can I eliminate the Schottky diode? (or it's extremely needed for inverse current...).

I initially select the PMV27UPE since from the datasheet it has a ultra low active resistance  but emulating its behaviour with spice it has a voltage drop of .7V... Where did I make a mistake? (is it a problem it's working in linear region even if for switching purposes?)

Additional info: I need a maximum of 500mA delivered to the Load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You connected Q1 drain to the wrong place.

With no USB power, R2 pulls the gate low, turning Q1 on. Its drain then pulls the gate high, turning it (partially) off again; it settles at 0.7V drop.

I think you want the drain connected to TEST-POINT1, then D1 prevents the gate voltage rising. (That way the Schottky diode drop only happens under USB power, where it doesn't matter).

Note also. Q1 body diode will charge the battery from USB power, which may be very bad. You may need the usual back-to-back pair of MOSFETs to provide isolation in both directions..

Answer (score 1):

With no USB, R2 pulls the mosfet gate to low, opening the mosfet allowing B+ to flow from source to drain, but at this point, since you have the mosfet's drain connected back to the gate, it will close immediately the mosfet (because you are putting B+ at the mosfet's gate (excluding the voltage drop across the resistor, which will affect almost nothing)), so you have an infinite loop on opening and closing the mosfet (the mosfet will open, voltage will start to rise on the drain and on the gate as well, and when voltage is enough to close the mosfet's gate, it will close and it will loop again), making it be "close all the time" (well only a very very very small current will flow).

All you need to do is to connect the mosfet's drain after the diode instead of before, not allowing the current to flow back to the mosfet's gate. And when you apply 5V with the USB, the mosfet will stop conducting, and the diode will allow the current to flow to the rest of the circuit - it sounds like it might work :) but you need to take into consideration that you have an internal mosfet diode, and when you apply 5V from the USB, it will flow back to the battery - this is not good!